# 및 is and or or?

Tags: vocabulary

Especially, we can see the word 및 in an office document or an advertisement. For instance, 10년 경력자 및 토잌 800이상 우대 (We like a person of 10 year's experience and toeic of 800 scores). Here 및 is always **and** ? And 및 can be used for the meaning **or** ?

Additional question : 10년 경력자 내지 토잌 800이상 우대. Here 내지 means and or or ?

Comment: did you see any sentences where it has been implied that it means or?

Comment: according to naver's dictionary it is only used as and: https://ko.dict.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=15006600

Comment: No reference. Just I am confusing and thank you for a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"및" should mean "and" in this case. The phrase you included has an ambiguous noun: the implied meaning of "토잌 800이상" is "people who scored 800 or higher on TOEIC."

Hence, the meaning of "10년 경력자 및 토잌 800이상 우대" would be "preference to people with 10+ years of experience **and** to people who scored 800+ on TOEIC."